# A point charge near a conducting cylinder

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, electromagnetic-induction, method-of-images

As we could figure out the point charge induced image charge on a conducting sphere in Jackson's book. Is there any way to figure out the point charge induced image charge form on a conducting cylinder/rod? 
Please give me some suggestions, references, literature on how to solve this.

Most of the papers I found are charge inside a cylinder, however, I'd like a cylinder sensing the point charge influence while the charge is moving.

ps. On conducting sphere Jackson Sec. 2.2 to 2.4